# Nested array value comparison with another array value in mongoose using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I get addedproducts array elements where productids' of addedproducts array match with every id in productids' array of  invitationfrom array(for a particular user email)  in the below structure?

```
var UserSchema = new Schema(
{   email: 
       { type: String, 
         unique: true, 
         required: true 
       },
    addedproducts:[ { 
           name: String,    
           productid:String,
           producttype:String 
        } ],
    invitationfrom : [ {
         fromemail: String,     
         productid:[String] 
   }]
}, {collection: 'user-data-db'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
User.find({'addedproducts.productid': "123456"}, {'invitationfrom.productid': "123456"})
            .exec(function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({message: err});
                }

                if (!user) {
                    return res.status(404).json({message: 'No Match Found'});
                } else {
                    return res.status(200).json(user);
                }
            });
```